# The requested content cannot be loaded-fancybox

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have radio button code below, when I clicked on that need to open fancybox modal window but while clicking it is saying 'the requested content cannot be loaded'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#cncstoreloc").fancybox({
    target: this,
    href: '#cnc',
    width: 1080,
        height: 400,
        autoSize: false,
        autoCenter: true,
        scrolling: 'auto',
        titleShow: false,
        title: null,
        centerOnScroll: true,
        margin: 0,
        padding: 30,
        //type: 'iframe'
        afterShow: function(){
            $('#quicksearch').on('click', function(){
            $('#cncstorepane').css('display','block');
            });
        },

        afterClose: function(){
            $('#radio_check').removeClass('radio_chk');
        }

}).on("click", function (evt) {

            $('#radio_check').addClass('radio_chk');
        });

});
```

Radio button code:

```
<div class="" id="clickncollect_form">
   <input type="radio" id="cncstoreloc" name="cncstoreloc">
    <label for="cncstoreloc">Test</label>
   <span id="radio_check" class="check"></span>
</div>
```

Content div to load in fancybox modal window:

```
<div style="display:none">
   <div class="main-container" id="cnc">
    <h1>CLICK & COLLECT</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea instead of loading the content why it's throwing an error.

Comment: I had written the below code but it won't working as excpt like not open in modal window.

Comment: Thanks for the addition of code. I've voted to reopen, but please clarify "not working" by editing the question further, thanks.

Comment: I have re-written my post could you reopen it.

Comment: I have already voted to reopen, it needs two more votes. Have you checked the entries in your Network browser panel?